# Fetch API Using Async/Await Return Value Unexpected

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

Here's the function:

```
const getUserIP = async () => {
  let response = await fetch('https://jsonip.com/');
  let json = await response.json();

  console.log(json.ip)
  return json.ip;
};
```

In the console, the IP address is logged as expected. However, when I save the 'IP address' to a variable:

```
const ip = getUserIP();
```

And then type `ip` in the console, the value is shown as:

```
Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: "/* my IP here*/" }
```

I've watched videos on YouTube who have used the same logic/syntax albeit for a different API, but it works. I've searched Google and SO and couldn't find a thread with the same issue.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Lots of duplicates of this question.  I marked one of them.  This is a common misunderstanding of how `async/await` works.  Worth reading some doc/articles on them.

Answer (score 5):

**[Async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value)** return Promises, you need to get that value as follow:

```
getUserIP().then(ip => console.log(ip)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Or, you can add the `async` declaration to the main function who calls the function `getUserIP`:

```
async function main() {
    const ip = await getUserIP();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions return a `Promise`, and its resolved value is whatever you return from it. To get `ip`, you must use `then`.

```
getUserIP().then(ip => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.then` to `getUserIP()` because `async` function is returning a promise.

```
getUserIp().then(ip => console.log(ip));
```

You can also

```
(async() => {
    const ip = await getUserIP();
    console.log(ip);
})();
```