# How to use fetch with async/await?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I start by saying that I am not 100% sure this is the problem, I mean using await and async.

This is the scenario:

I run this when I first load the page, and works fine, I get the `data`:

```
    externalContent(url);

    function externalContent(url) {
      fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        ...cool data...
      });
    }
```

But then I need to be able to click a button and re run that function with the `fetch`

So I do

```
    $(".alm-filters--button").on("click", function() {
      externalContent(url);
    });
```

But when I click, It gives me an error on  `.then(res => res.json())`

The error says: ***Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined***

I believe there is an asynchronous issue, I tried, but I do not know enough about using async and await, yet I tried:

```
    async function externalContent(url) {
      await fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
         ...cool data...
      });
    }
```

But et, I get the same error.

Comment: can you add a `.catch(console.error)` at the end of `fetch`? Is there any error that's caught?

Comment: Are you really sure that the error happens at `fetch(url).then(res => res.json())` and not at another part of your code?

Comment: @t.niese no I am not sure but consoles gives me that line and I everything works

Comment: Code seems to be fine. Add the catch at the end of the promise and see if there is an error.

Comment: If it really happens at that line, then this indicates that you overwrite the `fetch` function with another function, because `fetch(url).then(res => res.json())` should never result in that error, if `fetch`  refers to the fetch API of the browser. But I would guess that the problem happens somewhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch API Using Async/Await Return Value Unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661185/fetch-api-using-async-await-return-value-unexpected)

Comment: @HemantParashar nothing, I get the same error

Comment: I think your native `fetch` on window is being overridden by your code. Try this code in another browser or online sandbox.If it works...that's the case

Comment: This looks the same as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54949464/215552), but with `async` and `await` added on there to get around being a duplicate...

Comment: @HereticMonkey found the issue, i had another fetch() function defined from an old piece of code. I wanted to delete the other question but  couldn't since there was an answer. I have asked to close it. Not cheating.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Referring to [this article](https://dev.to/johnpaulada/synchronous-fetch-with-asyncawait) should take care of your issue. See the snippet as well.

```js
async function exampleFetch() {
    const response = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/2');
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
}

exampleFetch()
```

`await` substitutes for `.then()`, so when using `await fetch`, you don't need to use `.then()` at all.

Here are a couple other answers which deal with more or less the same issue:

1 - [How can I acces the values of my async fetch function? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034875/how-can-i-acces-the-values-of-my-async-fetch-function)

2 - [Fetch API Using Async/Await Return Value Unexpected [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661185/fetch-api-using-async-await-return-value-unexpected)

Comment: I updated the answer with a comment to clarify. The `const json` should have the same value as what you call `data`.

Comment: @dvlsg exactly it won't work, even the article he posted says it! You need to use await within an async function

Comment: turned it into a snippet, check it out now. yep there was a wrong line previously.

Comment: check my first part of the code in the question, I don't use await, what am I doing wrong then?

Comment: you can't `await` unless you use `async`. Yes, part of the issue is that you are not using an async function/

Comment: Original example doesn't seem wrong to me - in fact, it works when I paste it in my chrome console (or at least gives me the CORS error I expect). Are you sure those lines are the source of the error?

Comment: @JohnVandivier "part" what else? :)

Comment: @dvlsg I've been hours on it, the line in console gives me what I say in the question. I really don't get it. Would you come to chat?

Comment: @rob.m I don't see you in JavaScript chat?

Comment: async/await isn't needed for this scenario. It can be used, but it's not going to magically make a call to fetch() that doesn't return anything all of a sudden return something. the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: 100% agree fetch isn't needed here...actually I debugged with him in chat and the fetch function itself was being redefined lmao...but anyway the title is asking how to use it so that's what my answer's about even if it isn't needed

Comment: @t.niese we can do it but we don't need to use `.then` even with 1 line of code, for example with parentheses, it is even shorter and we don't need the intermediate variable `res`: `(await fetch("url")).text()`

Comment: @t.niese in fact there should be 2 `await` if we don't use `.then`: `var result = await (await fetch("url")).json(); console.log(result);`. I am not sure if the 2 `await` were required in the previous Firefox version I tested with.

Comment: I receive `Promise { <pending> }` when I attempt this example in RunJS for the actual return object, despite correct console printing. Same output even if I try and await the function call: `(async() => await exampleFetch())();`

Answer (score -1):

my workable fetch pattern

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function downloadTxt(url) {
     const response = await fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors',
    })
    return await response.text();
}

(async () => {
     const txt = await downloadTxt("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all");
     console.log(txt)
})();
```

Comment: [Don't forget to handle errors though!](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
async  function  fetchApi(){
  const view = document.querySelector('#view');
     await  fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth/login')
             .then(response=>response.json())
             .then(json=>{
```

### this is for view the api response on the screen instead of console

```
              if(view.innerHTML==""){
                for (const key in json) {
                if (json.hasOwnProperty.call(json, key)) {
                  view.innerHTML += `<h4>${key}</h4> : ${json[key]}`;  
                }
              }
              }
              console.log(json);
            })
            .catch(err=>{
              console.error(err);
            })
  }
  

although it also works perfectly without async await
```

### follow the both portion of the code block ^